# Zurb Foundation with unusual column sizing

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Our designer wants me to create a grid, where each column is a different width: 124px, 132px, 143px, 146px and 152px.

Can Zurb Foundation be modified to build grids with such peculiar column widths?

Comment: Zurb foundation is a responsive website framework. The size of colums will vary depending on screen size, resolution

Comment: Yes you're right @DawoodAwan. Assuming I've viewing on 1024px res monitor, is it possible to specify that each grid column has a marginally different width than it's neighbour? They want me to build a really unusual design.

Comment: I don't think you can. I suggest you create your own columns, in seperate css file. or use % to create column width

Comment: Thanks @DawoodAwan, I reckon that's the right answer, you should submit it and I'll accept it. I'm going to build my own grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. I suggest you create your own columns, in seperate css file. or use % to create column width